# Disable verbose debugging in unix using set command

Tags: debugging, unix

In my bash script in unix, I added
`set -x` 
to be able and debug output. 
for example I can see:

```
+qualityPostActionPDT.sh:23> echo -e Our current directory is /Projects/QualityTest
Our current directory is /Projects/QualityTest
```

Now i want to disable it. How can I do that please, I don't need the verbose anymore..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Saying:

```
set +x
```

would disable trace.

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> Using `‘+’` rather than `‘-’` causes these options to be turned off. The
>   options can also be used upon invocation of the shell. The current set
>   of options may be found in `$-`.